# If $2f(x-1)+f(1-x)=2x$ then $f(x)=?$

Tags: functions

We've been given a function:
$$2f(x-1)+f(1-x)=2x$$
So now someone please teach me how to find:
$$f(x)=???$$
Sorry! Really sorry but I don't have any ideas about it! Please tell me how can I solve this kind of questions?

Comment: I would start by substituting $x-1=y$. Then your functional equation becomes $$f(-y) = 2(y-1-f(y))$$

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Ummm.. nothing yet!

Comment: @greedoid I was exactly now thinkin' about it!

Comment: @greedoid would you tell me what Dr.mathva has done?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\to 1-x$: $$2f(-x)+f(x)=2-2x$$
$x\to 1+x$: $$2f(x)+f(-x)=2+2x$$ $$\Rightarrow 4f(x)+2f(-x)=4+4x$$

Subtracting: $$3f(x)=2+6x$$ $$\Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{2}{3}+2x$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $t= x-1$ then we get $$2f(t)+f(-t)= 2t+2$$ (which is valid for all real $t$ since the linear function $x\mapsto x-1$ is surjective) and if we swich $t$ with $-t$ we get

$$2f(-t)+f(t)= -2t+2$$ So $$ 2(2t+2-2f(t))+f(t)= -2t+2$$

which give us: $$f(t)= 2t+2/3$$

Comment: Oh  big thanks to you. Just a little point: Can you explain how $f(-t)$ works?

Comment: Expres form 1.st $f(-t) = 2t+2-2f(t)$ and plug it in second equation.

Comment: @greedoid $f(t)=2t+2/3$

Comment: No I mean how did you switch between $t$ and $-t$??

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  Thanks

Comment: @user602338 I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I meam how first equation turned into the second one?

Comment: How did you switch from t to -t?

Comment: @user602338 For the second equation, set $z=1-x$. You now get an equation in $z$, then set $z=t$

Comment: Ahh, just write $-t$ instead of $t$ where ever you see $t$.

Comment: So how 2t+2 became -2t+2 ?

Comment: $2(-t)+2 = -2t+2$

Comment: How switching between t and -t affect on the 2t+2?

Answer (score 2):

$2f(x-1)+f(1-x)=2x\Rightarrow 2f(y)+f(-y)=2(y+1)\ ,(1)\Rightarrow 2f(-y)+f(y)=2(-y+1)\Rightarrow -4f(-y)-2f(y)=-4(-y+1)\ , (2)$

$(1)+(2)\Rightarrow -3f(-y)=6y-2\Rightarrow -3f(y)=-6y-2\Rightarrow f(y)=2y+\dfrac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

$2f(x-1)+f(1-x)=2x$

Set $y=1-x\implies x=1-y$

$2f(-y)+f(y)=2(1-y)$

Set $y=x-1\implies x=y+1$

$2f(y)+f(-y)=2(1+y)$

Eliminate $f(-y)$ between the two equations:

$\implies f(y)=2y+\frac23$